# change the dropdown listing color when hover on listing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<form name="form" method="" action="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="search-category-container">
                <label class="styled-select">
                    <select name="dep" class="dropdown-product drop-select">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>Australia</option>
                        <option>Canada</option>
                        <option>UK</option>
                     </select>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
            <div class="search-category-container">
                <label class="styled-select">
                    <select name="cname" class="dropdown-product drop-select">
                        <option>Contact name</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-search-icon"><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This code is for changing the product according to the city. But when I applied bootstrap, a dropdown listing showing me a default color (blue) on hover. I want to change the drop-down listing color on hover.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is to change a bootstrap dropdown item background color on hover, what you have to do is to override the existing css class .dropdown-item:hover

```
.dropdown-item:hover {
   background-color: red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the arrow color and text, try this:

```css
.styled-select select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 168px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.styled-select:hover {
  outline: none;
  width: 140px;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/Vector_down_arrow_changed.svg/16px-Vector_down_arrow_changed.svg.png") no-repeat right #fff;
}

select {
  outline: none;
}

.drop-select:hover  {
  color: green !important;
}

option {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" method="" action="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="search-category-container">
        <label class="styled-select">
                    <select name="dep" class="dropdown-product drop-select">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>Australia</option>
                        <option>Canada</option>
                        <option>UK</option>
                     </select>
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
      <div class="search-category-container">
        <label class="styled-select">
                    <select name="cname" class="dropdown-product drop-select">
                        <option>Contact name</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```